# Google Bigquery: How to update partition expiration time for a partitioned table?

Tags: google-bigquery

Bigquery documentation says its possible to update the partition time expiry for a partitioned table. Whereas I'm able to do that only for ingestion time partitioned tables. I tried the below:

```
  bq query --use_legacy_sql=false ' 
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [DATASET].partitioned_table_ingestion_time ( 
      event_date DATE NOT NULL, 
      event_id INT64) 
  PARTITION BY DATE(_PARTITIONTIME)
  OPTIONS( 
     partition_expiration_days=10, 
     description="table partitioned by ingestion time and with expiry" 
   )'
```

Update query and result:

```
  # update expiry to 7 days = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 = 604800 s
  bq update --time_partitioning_expiration 604800 [PROJECT-ID]:[DATASET].partitioned_table_ingestion_time

  Table 'PROJECT-ID]:[DATASET].partitioned_table_ingestion_time' successfully updated.
```

Now for the partitioned table:

```
  bq query --use_legacy_sql=false ' 
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [DATASET].partitioned_table ( 
      event_date DATE NOT NULL, 
      event_id INT64) 
  PARTITION BY event_date
  OPTIONS( 
     partition_expiration_days=10, 
     description="table partitioned by event_date with expiry" 
   )'
```

The update fails in this case

```
  # update expiry to 7 days
  bq update --time_partitioning_expiration 604800 [PROJECT-ID]:[DATASET].partitioned_table 

  BigQuery error in update operation: Cannot change partitioning spec for a partitioned table.
```

How can I update the partition time expiry here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this instead, specifying the partitioning field as part of the `bq update` command:

```
bq update --time_partitioning_field=event_date \
  --time_partitioning_expiration 604800 [PROJECT-ID]:[DATASET].partitioned_table
```

Edit: you can now use the [`ALTER TABLE SET OPTIONS` statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_set_options_statement) to change the partition expiration as well. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE `project-name`.dataset_name.table_name
SET OPTIONS (partition_expiration_days=7);
```

Comment: worked like a charm! Once again, inadequate documentation from google cloud platform! And agree, it would be nice to have this feature as a DDL statement. Feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78378468)

Comment: Thanks! DDL statements are something that my team handles, so I assigned the request to myself. I also filed [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78447904) about the update restriction and misleading error.

Comment: See official documentation [Manage partitioned tables > Set the partition expiration](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#partition-expiration)

Answer (score 3):

if you want to remove partition expiration completely, set `NULL` for `partition_expiration_days` option

```
ALTER TABLE `project-name`.dataset_name.table_name
SET OPTIONS (partition_expiration_days=NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, When I added time_partitioning_type and time_partitioning_field option to command, it was successfully updated.

Answer (score 0):

we can try updating this way:-

[set partition Expiration time on Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzvS9.png)

Comment: Please write relevant sections of the answer here itself as links might change over time.

Comment: thanks for suggestion we can simply also do this way





:-

bq update --time_partitioning_expiration (time in second) Dataset.table_name

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set *time_partitioning_expiration* and *time_partitioning_type*

Below is an example to set retention for an hourly partitioned table to 180 days.

```
bq update --time_partitioning_expiration 15552000 --time_partitioning_type HOUR  GCP_PROJECT:dataset.bq_table
```

Official documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#update_the_partition_expiration